# PHP - Creating and uploading to directories

Tags: php, mysql, session, mkdir, subdirectory

I am trying to upload files to a directory created with PHP. The application should create a sub-directory inside the root directory according to a User's UserID. (for e.g. files/14/).

The directory is being created, however the files are not being uploaded to the sub-directory.

This is the code:

```
<?php 


                include("dbConfig.php");

                $Username = $_SESSION["username"];

                global $userid;

                $Password = $_SESSION["password"];

                $Password = md5($Password);

                $sql = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Username = '".$Username."'";

                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                        $userid = $row['UserID'];

                }


                echo $userid;

                $dirname = (string)$userid;

                $filename = ("/folder/" . "$dirname" . "/");

                if (!file_exists($filename))

                {

                            mkdir("files/$dirname", 0777);

                            if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

                            echo "<div id='files_table'><table class='center'.><tr><td>";

                            $dest = ("files/" . $dirname . "{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");

                            foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

                            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest );

                            echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], " uploaded.", "<br>";

                            }

                 }else {


                        if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

                        echo "<div id='files_table'><table class='center'.><tr><td>";

                            $dest = ("files/" . $dirname . "{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");

                            foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

                            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest );

                            echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], " uploaded.", "<br>";


                    }
                    echo "</td></tr></table></div><br><br>";
                    }




                 }

            }
```

[image: Directory Structure]

Answer (score 0):

Brain,
PHP support one file upload at one time, if you have many file fields in your form, you should keep "$dest = ("files/" . $dirname . "{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");" in the loop.
$Key will be empty outside the loop.

Loop can't be on temp_name, temp_name is a temp copy of the file which php is going to upload.

Comment: The HTML 5 upload form allows you to upload multiple files at once (5mB size limit of each file)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code:

Note: I corrected some errors in your code too. please compare.

```
<?php 
include("dbConfig.php");
$Username = $_SESSION["username"];
global $userid;
$Password = $_SESSION["password"];
$Password = md5($Password);

$sql = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Username = '".$Username."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $userid = $row['UserID'];
}


$dirname = (string)$userid;
$filename = ("$dirname" . "/");
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    mkdir("files/$dirname", 0775);
}

if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    echo "<div id='files_table'><table class='center'.><tr><td>";        
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
        $dest = ("files/" . $dirname . "{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest );
        echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], " uploaded.", "<br>";
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: It still shows the same errors and the same thing happens. Files are uploaded in the root directory